# Do dojo widgets emit an event when destroyed or can you force one to?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a custom widget based on _WidgetBase. I create it in JavaScript and would like to know when it is destroyed.

Code in parent:

```
var editRelatedTableWidget = new EditRelatedTable().placeAt(dom.byId("docEditorWidget");
editRelatedTableWidget.startup();
on(editRelatedTableWidget, "click", function () {console.log("DIJIT CLICKED"); }); // works
on(editRelatedTableWidget, "destroy", function () { console.log("DIJIT DESTROYED"); }); // does not ever happen
```

I have tried attaching to unload, destroy and remove - none of these events are fired. The widget actually destroys itself when a button is clicked, so I tried forcing it to emit an event, like this (In the widget):

```
on.emit(this,"destroy");
this.destroyRecursive();
```

But the parent didn't detect an event then either. Any suggestions?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

We can use the uninitialize function of the widget. This function will be called when the widget will be destroyed.
Ex:

```
 editRelatedTableWidget.uninitialize = function(){ console.log('destroyed');}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Is there any place this pattern is documented? Having a hard time finding reference material for dojo.

Comment: Thanks. The fact is dojo source files itself are a great source of documentations. This one I found it from the _Widget.js file inside dijit folder. So best way to download all the source files and go through them for the events/methods that can be overridden in our own widgets.

Comment: If you look at the source files as you suggest, you will actually see that `uninitialize` is [deprecated](https://github.com/dojo/dijit/blob/1.10.4/_WidgetBase.js#L671-L672).  `destroy` generally serves the same purpose, but you would not want to directly assign it a function - you'd want to use `dojo/aspect.after` to attach additional logic to it.

Answer (score 3):

[`dojo/aspect.after`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/aspect.html) is a good solution for cases like this, where you want to do something when a certain method is called, but there is no event to listen to.

Example:

```
aspect.after(editRelatedTableWidget, 'destroy', function () {
    console.log(this.id + ' destroyed');
}, true);
```

The `true` argument after the callback is the `receiveArguments` flag, which tells `aspect.after` to send the original arguments as-is to the callback, and more importantly, ignore its return value, preserving the original function's return value.  If this flag is `false`, the callback is passed the original return value and an array of the arguments, and must explicitly return the value the function should now return.

Answer (score 1):

I found that in order to emit a custom event from a dojo widget, the widget needs to inherit Evented (dojo/Evented).  e.g.

```
declare ([_WidgetBase, Evented], {
  _done: function () {
  on.emit(this, "done");
}
```

The calling code can now listen for the done event, e.g.

```
on(editRelatedTableWidget, "done", function () {console.log("it's done");})
```